# How can I get this Javascript calculator to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a simple calculator, but it's not working. How can I get it to work?

```js
$(function() {
  var firstNumber = $('#firstNumber')
  var operation = $('#operation')
  var secondNumber = $('#secondNumber')
  var calculate = $('button')

  calculate.click(getResult)

  function getResult(firstNumber, operation, secondNumber) {
    if (operation === '+') {
      var result = firstNumber.val() + secondNumber.val()
    } else if (operation === '-') {
      var result = firstNumber.val() - secondNumber.val()
    } else if (operation === '*') {
      var result = firstNumber.val() * secondNumber.val()
    } else {
      var result = firstNumber.val() / secondNumber.val()
    }
  }
  $('#result').text(result)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='firstNumber' placeholder='Enter a number'>
<input type='text' id='operation' placeholder='Enter an operation'>
<input type='text' id='secondNumer' placeholder='Enter another number'>
<br>
<button>Calculate</button>
<br>
<p>The result is <span id='result'></span></p>
```

Comment: When the site tells you to include the actual code in your question when you include a link, the solution is not to ignore the warning and include irrelevant non-code, but to *actually post the code in your question*, in a [MCVE]. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

- calculate.click(getResult) does not pass what the function expects. Remove firstNumber, operation, secondNumber from the function arguments
- rename the span (not recommended to have same name for functions, vars and html elements)
- Make sure the strings are cast to number
- only have one var result
- $('#resultSpan').text(result) inside the function that uses it
- Typo in secondNumer
- missing .val() on operation
- Do not allow division by 0
- Anything but the 4 allowed operators should give error (you could also test for numbers before calculating)
- I changed the button to type="button" - if you ever wrapped your elements in a form, it would submit the form

Here is working version

```js
function getResult() {
  var result,
    firstNumber  = +$('#firstNumber').val(), // casting value to number
    secondNumber = +$('#secondNumber').val(),
    operation    = $('#operation').val();
    console.log(firstNumber,operation,secondNumber)
  if (operation === '+') {
    result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
  } else if (operation === '-') {
    result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
  } else if (operation === '*') {
    result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
  } else if (operation === '/') {
    result = (secondNumber === 0) ? "Cannot divide by 0": (firstNumber / secondNumber);
  }
  else result = "Only use +,-,* or /";
  $('#resultSpan').text(result)
}

// onload does not have to have every line of the script in it
$(function() {
  $('button').click(getResult)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='firstNumber' placeholder='Enter a number'>
<input type='text' id='operation' placeholder='Enter an operation'>
<input type='text' id='secondNumber' placeholder='Enter another number'>
<br>
<button type="button">Calculate</button>
<br>
<p>The result is <span id='resultSpan'></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. You should not expect `firstNumber`, `operator` and `secondNumber` to be passed as argument to your `getResult` function. Leave those parameters out -- you already assigned the appropriate DOM elements to variables with those names.
2. The output of the result should not happen outside of the function -- move that inside `getResult`.
3. There is a typo in the HTML `id` attribute for `secondNumber` (`b` is missing)
4. `val()` returns a string, so when you do `+`, it will concatenate those two input strings. To get an arithmetic addition, first convert those strings to number, like for instance with the unary `+`
5. `operation` is never `+`,`-`,... It is the `input` element, so you have to take the `.val()` of it.

Here is a corrected version of your script:

```js
$(function() {
  var firstNumber = $('#firstNumber')
  var operation = $('#operation')
  var secondNumber = $('#secondNumber')
  var calculate = $('button')

  calculate.click(getResult)

  function getResult() {
    var result
    var op = operation.val()
    if (op === '+') {
      result = +firstNumber.val() + +secondNumber.val()
    } else if (op === '-') {
      result = firstNumber.val() - secondNumber.val()
    } else if (op === '*') {
      result = firstNumber.val() * secondNumber.val()
    } else {
      result = firstNumber.val() / secondNumber.val()
    }
    $('#result').text(result)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='firstNumber' placeholder='Enter a number'>
<input type='text' id='operation' placeholder='Enter an operation'>
<input type='text' id='secondNumber' placeholder='Enter another number'>
<br>
<button>Calculate</button>
<br>
<p>The result is <span id='result'></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `secondNumber` div had a typo. I think you were trying to use an `IIFE` but since the codewas executing at document load, your primary variables were `undefined`.  In this example I am using a `click()` handler and assigning the values to variables at call time (assuming you entered values in the inputs).

To perform math operations, you need to parse numerical values from your inputs, otherwise your code would simply concatenate the values and not compute them.  You can use `parseFloat()` for decimal values or `parseInt()` for whole numbers depending on the type of values you want.

The code below worked in my pen:

```
  $('#calculate').click( function() {
       var result;
       var operation = $('#operation').val()
       var firstNumber = parseFloat($('#firstNumber').val())
       var secondNumber = parseFloat($('#secondNumber').val())

       if (operation === '+') {
           result = firstNumber + secondNumber
       } else if (operation === '-') {
           result = firstNumber - secondNumber
       } else if (operation === '*') {
           result = firstNumber * secondNumber
       } else {
           result = firstNumber / secondNumber
       }

       $('#result').text(result.toFixed(2))
   })
```

Comment: I you click "copy snippet to answer" you will have the original code to play with in a [mcve]. From scratcu you can click the `[<>]` snippet editor